# Object pattern matching results in uninitialized variable

Tags: pattern-matching, null-check, c#-9.0

Pattern matching to find whether a value is not `null` was done using the `is` keyword with the respective expected type (included a cast if necessary). The pattern `!(obj is object instance)` returns `true` if `obj` is not `null` and `false` if `obj` is `null`. At the same time if `obj` is not `null` it is captured in the variable `instance`.

```cs
[Fact]
public void Old_pattern_matching_for_non_null_object()
{
    var obj = new object();
    if (!(obj is object instance)) // false
        return;

    if (instance is null) // false
        throw new Exception("Never reached");

    // this does not throw an exception (test passes)
}
```

With C#8 a new way of writing this was introduced using `{ }` to denote `non-null` (without casting) which "simplified" the code to

```cs
[Fact]
public void Csharp_8_pattern_matching_for_non_null_object()
{
    var obj = new object();
    if (!(obj is { } instance)) // false
        return;

    if (instance is null) // false
        throw new Exception("Never reached");

    // this does not throw an exception (test passes)
}
```

With C#9 the new keyword `not` was introduced which was intended to simplify patterns such as `!(x is null)` to `x is not null`. If I now try to apply the new `not` keyword to a pattern includig `{ }` I get a quite surprising result:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Csharp_9_pattern_matching_for_non_null_object()
{
    var obj = new object();
    if (obj is not { } instance) // false
        return;

    if (instance is null) // true
        throw new Exception("Why the heck is this null");

    // this does throw an exception (test fails)
}
```

Even though that `obj` is not `null` the `instance` variable is not initialized. And to get one better, by avoiding the `obj` variable `instance` will be initialized:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Csharp_9_pattern_matching_for_non_null_object_without_obj_variable()
{
    if (new object() is not { } instance) // false
        return;

    if (instance is null) // false
        throw new Exception("Never reached");
        
    // this does not throw an exception (test passes)
}
```

Does anybody know if this is a desired behavior? If yes, what is the intent behind it?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. I would open an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues

Comment: That last test case [looks very broken](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQZgAJ1CBhQgb10JuKJQBZCBZACgEpLraeA3CBIQD2wAFaEAvIQB2cAO7CxcAMYwOAbm48aASwBmhViPE6oMoTEqEAvoR3TYEacricA9G8J6IAGyhwtbR4UAHZNHECefUN7R2c4OzNpAFcfH3dPGARkgJwgoJgACwQhBVkFAFEADxcABxgdIWlWACIAdUKAT0IihMKVAGtEnsLTGVSfFvZwnmtAwIJiJgA5Di48/OjWcsVRFTVOMekLK1tYmCcXDK9ff0j80PD73QNWc8uEo4nr7z9c/O0RRKZXkhGqdQaTVayzgvEQhAQcAgyn6ABMpjNaHMcNYgA==). It compiles to `object obj = new object(); if (obj == null || obj != null) return; throw ...`.

Comment: OP posted on [csharplang discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4215), and a member pointed out that it's [already been filed and fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49708). The fix went in 2 days ago, and the latest master on SharpLab is 3 days old, so the fix doesn't appear there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yari Halberstadt pointed out this is actually a compiler bug. I posted a question regarding this on the [Csharplang discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4215) and was informed that this was already fixed.

As canton7 pointed out the issue was fixed recently and has at this point in time not been released yet.

Once released all example test-cases should pass. The failing test-case is actually a valid usecase according to [this C#9 release blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#logical-patterns) where the following example is used:

```cs
if (e is not Customer c) { throw ... } // if this branch throws or returns...
var n = c.FirstName; // ... c is definitely assigned here
```